# where I really should be adding and removing notification observers in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

With Swift, something changed, for instance `dealloc()` can no longer be used in Swift-based ViewControllers instead `deinit`.

I searched, found somebody said that add notification observer in `viewWillAppear` method and remove in `viewDidDisappear`, and others said maybe `init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` & `deinit` is a good choice.

I really want to know what's the best programming practice?

Comment: You add notifications as soon as you want to start receiving them and remove notifications when you want to stop receiving them. What's difficult to understand about that? Also, dealloc was rarely the right place. The "best practice" is different for every notification.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert Why dealloc was rarely the right place? Could you give any use-case that `dealloc` definitely isn't a good choice? Thanks.

Comment: Because there are situations where dealloc doesn't get called when you might expect it to. Memory management is extremely complicated, especially when you throw ARC into the picture. In my opinion you should never do anything in dealloc except pass on the dealloc (via release) to other objects. Apple's documentation backs this up. They say you should "avoid" doing other things in dealloc. Dealloc is a bad choice in *every* situation where you might use it to de-register for a notification. If possible you should always be removing the notification before the object is deallocated.

Comment: If you have a view controller that observes a notification, then you should remove the notification when the user taps a button that removes the view from the screen.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really a matter of which is better practice, it really depends on which best suits your needs.

If for example, you have a view controller that should respond to notifications it's observing until it is deinitialized, go with that route. Or, if you're doing things like updating the interface of the view controller based on information received in the notification, you may only need to do so when that view controller is actually visible, in which case viewWillAppear:/viewDidDisappear: are good options.

Answer (score 0):

If you add notification observer in `viewWillAppear`, you can have a problem with such case:

```
    let detailsViewController = UIViewController(nibName: "DetailsViewController", bundle: nil);
    // your detailsViewController don't handle some notifications, because it isn't in view hierarchy yet, and viewWillAppear hasn't called yet
    // ...
    self.presentViewController(detailsViewController, animated: true, completion: nil);
    // Only after this code, your detailsViewController start to handle some notifications, because you declare adding notification observer in viewWillAppear
```

So I think you right - `init(coder)` and `deinit()` will be the better choice

`viewWillAppear` and `viewDidDissapear` will be the good choice, when you need to handle view-based notifications - for example keyboard appearance